# Missing footer on first Beamer slide of TikZ example

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm having problems with this particular TikZ example:

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/prims-algorithm/

When I change the theme, for instance:

```
\usetheme{Madrid}
```

the footer is not working on the first slide, but it is on the rest of them. Any idea how to solve this particular problem?

Comment: (The newer question has a better mwe, so I propose to close the old question as a duplicate of the new one.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why, but the `\pause` command seems to be causing troubles. If you replace

```
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \pause
    \foreach \source / \dest in {d/a,d/f,a/b,b/e,e/c,e/g}
        \path<+->[selected edge] (\source.center) -- (\dest.center);
    \foreach \source / \dest / \fr in {d/b/4,d/e/5,e/f/5,b/c/6,f/g/7}
        \path<\fr->[ignored edge] (\source.center) -- (\dest.center);
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

by

```
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \foreach \source / \dest / \fr in {d/a/2,d/f/3,a/b/4,b/e/5,e/c/6,e/g/7}
        \path<\fr->[selected edge] (\source.center) -- (\dest.center);
    \foreach \source / \dest / \fr in {d/b/4,d/e/5,e/f/5,b/c/6,f/g/7}
        \path<\fr->[ignored edge] (\source.center) -- (\dest.center);
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

it works.

Comment: I had this problem with different first slides also in my presentations. There must be some bug in `beamer`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer what have you done in order to solve the bug? I have the same problem, and my document is *very* long in order to calculate the overlays again.

Comment: @manooooh sorry, that is almost 10 years ago, I cannot recall my solution.

Comment: @MartinScharrer oh. Do you have idea if there is an open issue about this? Any easy fix solution?

Comment: @manoooh No, sorry