# \pause in tikzpicture breaks footline

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, header-footer, pause

I've discovered that you can `\pause` within a `tikzpicture`, which works well until I switched the theme to one with a footline.

I've created a "test case" that illustrates the problem.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\providecommand\thispdfpagelabel[1]{} % Not sure what this does but our installation requires it.
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Madrid} % Has a footline.

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{test}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node at (0, 1) {Hello};
      \pause
      \node at (0, 0) {World};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This creates two slides, but the footline is only drawn on the second (the headline/title appears on both). Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Ouch!  A bit of testing shows that putting a `\pause` inside a `tikzpicture` _really_ messes up the pausing.  As an interim solution, you could use the `\node<overlay specification>` syntax or one of the other methods of hiding/revealing stuff in beamer.  But a plain `\pause` really does seem to be specially weird.

Comment: I wouldn't use pause, but I've had no problem with `\onslide` and friends...

Comment: Is this the same problem as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10871/missing-footer-on-first-beamer-slide-of-tikz-example?

Comment: Yes, it looks like the same problem.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think the problem is that `\pause` isn't smart enough. The footline appears in the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\providecommand\thispdfpagelabel[1]{} % Not sure what this does but our installation requires it.
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Madrid} % Has a footline.

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{test}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node at (0, 1) {Hello};
\onslide<2->{\node at (0, 0) {World};}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

That is, if you put your text to appear on the second slide in a `\onslide<2->{}` it will work. Or for a little more automation, use `\onslide<+->{}` which automatically increments things.

Not quite as intuitive as the pause command, but it does allow you more control...

Comment: I'll use \onslide<+-> then, thanks.
At least I don't have to number things manually that way.

Answer (score 41):

I just stumbled over this issue and found another work-around that does not require nesting lots of paused elements in braces: Add `\onslide<1->` at the end of the `tikzpicture` environment (strangely it does not work if you put it after the environment):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\providecommand\thispdfpagelabel[1]{} % Not sure what this does but our installation requires it.
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Madrid} % Has a footline.

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{test}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node at (0, 1) {Hello};
      \pause
      \node at (0, 0) {World};
      \onslide<1->
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does it work, and is this safe to use?

Comment: It seems that `\pause` affects „stuff after it“, where „stuff“ seems to range too far than intended. A `\onslide<1->` delimits the effect of the previous `pause`, and as it selects all overlays, makes sure that the following stuff is executed always. I believe this is safe.

Comment: I had this problem when using `\pause` inside `displaymath`, but I couldn't get this solution to work adequately in that cause. Either the footnote appeared only in transitions outside the `displaymath` or only inside the `displaymath`, but not both. The only way I could get it to work was with Seamus's solution.

Comment: This `\onslide<1->` trick works perfectly with the `tcolorbox` package's environments as well, so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No guarantees that this won't break something else, but you could try this patch:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\AtEndEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\onslide<1->}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{test}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node at (0, 1) {Hello};
      \pause
      \node at (0, 0) {World};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```