# Tabular inside tcolorbox breaks beamer \pause?

Tags: tables, beamer, tcolorbox

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  some text before
  \pause
  \begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
       cell1 & cell2\\\pause
       cell3 & cell4
    \end{tabular}
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \pause
  some text after
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The expected result would be that "some text after" only appears on the fourth slide, but "some text after" is already visible on the second slide, then disappears on the third and then reappears in the fourth.

[image]

Any hint on what's going on?

Notes:

- the same result occurs if the `tabularx` tcolorbox key is used instead of tabular
- my actual workaround for this is to use `\only` or `\uncover`, but I'm more interested in the reason why this doesn't work.

edit: it seems that the tcolorbox environment interferes with the pause counter. <strike>If **after** the tcolorbox envirnoment you put</strike>

```
\setcounter{beamerpauses}{#}
```

where `#` is equal to the number of `\pause` issued **before** the tcolorbox environment everything works fine.

Uhm, actually that works only in a very specific scenario

Comment: No problem if I replace `tcolorbox` with `mdframed`. So it is probably something inside the `tcolorbox` package. (+1) for the question, now I'm curious too.

Comment: And if you want the warnings to go away, use a more sizeable font like `lmodern`. `\usepackage{lmodern}`

Comment: @masu, of course, that's just the MWE, it's not code that I'm actually using somewhere...

Comment: I've suspected that of course, but who knows. Most people don't submit their MWE with warnings if they're avoidable with one line. But it seems legit to do that here and rule out the font change from the possible causes.

Comment: @masu so let me tell you a funny story about most people: most people don't submit MWEs at all! No, wait, most people don't even use LaTeX! So let's just shut down the site and move on with our lives :)

Comment: That would be a shame. True story, I know. But this does not prove my statement false (mathematically speaking). ;)

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use `\pause` inside `tabular` in the first place... as the `beamer` manual states:

> This command does not work inside `amsmath` environments like `align`, since these do really wicked things.

Your main problem is independent from `tabular`, it's even independent from `tcolorbox` itself. It's bad interaction between `setbeamercovered{invisible}` mode of `beamer` and `\endpgfpicture` (`tcolorbox` uses `TikZ/pgf` as far as I know). The following example shows, that when there are more `\pause`-s inside the `tikzpicture` the interpreter fails to hide the upcoming pauses (note: even in another `tikzpicture` afterwards).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  some text before
  \pause
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node at (0, 3) {Hello};
      \pause
      \node at (0, 2) {World};
      \pause
      \node at (0, 1) {and you};
      \pause
      \node at (0, 0) {and you};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \pause
  some text after
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

((As a workaround one could use `\setbeamercovered{transparent=0}`. But this still got issues with `tabular`... where you shouldn't use `\pause`... and some issues with the `\tcolorbox` coloring...))

So:

- avoid using `\pause` inside `tabular`
- avoid using `\pause` inside `tikz` therefore inside `tcolorbox`
- avoid using any combination of the above

Comment: the question linked seems to be about a different issue, this should be a comment, not an answer. -1

Comment: @Lep I didn't say, that the question is about the same issue. I would have marked it as a duplicate that case... and what you've just used as an argument for downvote, is flagging cause, not a downvoting one... And I've referred THE TOPIC, not the question. Check [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70051/36821) and the second comment for example -- this case it would be `\onslide<2->`, but it practically solves and describes it.

Comment: I think you are not understanding the question. The OP said that he already has a workaround for the issue, the problem is why some tabular inside a tcolorbox breaks `\pause`. Since there is no tikz in the MWE, if the problem is some interaction with tikz than it is probably a bug that needs to be addressed. Also, you are pausing the tikz picture in the wrong way in your answer. You need to `node<+->`, not `\pause`. It works fine if you pause it correctly

Comment: @Lep `tcolorbox` draws with `TikZ/pgf` as far as I know. And you can't use the "correct" way here. I was writing about `TikZ` because this is the lower level stuff what causes the problem in the first place.

Comment: In your code you can use the correct way, the problem is exactly that since in the original MWE there are no nodes or tikz elements involved, you should be able to use `\pause`, but it turns out you are not. So (i) this is a bug that can be solved or (ii) users should be warned that `\pause` don't work as expected in tcolorbox. Your answer does not address (i) nor (ii), it just adds more information to the question and should really be a comment or added to the question itself.

Comment: @Lep The OP asked about what is happening not if it is a bug... So the answer should be a description of the happenings (as my answer is one). "It can't be solved" is NOT an answer here! I'm tired of arguing, I'll leave now.

Comment: unfortunately the new solution fails if you have nested tcolorbox

Comment: To see it failing, just add another pause at the end and some other text after it. This also happens if you specify the pauses counter manually as I tried.