# tcolorbox with beamer

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox, pause

The MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tcolorbox}
A\pause B
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
A\pause B
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

produces three slides: `A-AB`, `AB-A`, and `AB-AB`, which is not what I would expect (`A-`, `AB-A`, and `AB-AB`).

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144912/32291) somebody advises not to use `\pause` at all inside a `tcolorbox`, but the [manual](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) does mention a `beamer` skin, so I guess it must have support for `beamer`. Is there a better way to do the above?

Comment: Well, the manual says "This skin resembles boxes known from the `beamer` class and therefore is called ’beamer’." The presence of the skin doesn't imply support for `beamer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\only` instead works, though it is a bit more work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tcolorbox}
A\only<2->{B}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\only<3->{A}\only<4>{B}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you also know a way to prevent the `tcolorbox` to become smaller if the text is still hidden?

Comment: @Carucel To fix the size, try with `\visible` instead of `\only`