# Beamer - Using \pause within tcboxmath

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox

I'm using the package tcolorbox with the library theorems. I'm having issues with \pause when imbedded within a \tcboxmath: instead of hiding the following part of the frame, it hides only the following part in the box, showing all the rest of the frame after the box.

Below is a mwe. Thanks for your help.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
If I put a pause in a tcboxmath frame like here: $\tcboxmath{\cos(x+\pi) = \pause -\cos(x)}$, this is what happens...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: What do you expect before `pause`? half `tcbox` or "this is what happens" hidden?

Comment: I expect "this is what happens" hidden.

Comment: As I posed below, yes (incredible that we've posted this a exactly the sae time!), even though the answer is quite problematic in my line of work: changing to tcolorbox raises here quite a problem... I haven't figured out why this happens sometimes and not always in tcolorbox enironment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My problem isn't after all limited to the use of `tcboxmath` as the same thing happens in some `tcolorbox` environment - though not all... The problem has actually already been raised here [Tabular inside tcolorbox breaks beamer \pause?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144889/tabular-inside-tcolorbox-breaks-beamer-pause), and seems to be linked with the use of Tikz. The workaround is to use `\only` instead of `\pause`.