# how to keep footline when we use \setbeamercovered{invisible} in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, header-footer, overlays

when i use `\setbeamercovered{invisible}`  the footline disappear in the whole tikzpicture frames:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{warsaw}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{frame}
\setbeamercovered{invisible}%transparent=0}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.5cm, auto]  
\tikzset{
    mynode/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,draw=black, top color=green, bottom color=red!80,very thick, inner sep=1em, minimum size=3em, text centered},
    myarrow/.style={->, >=latex', shorten >=.1pt},%, thick
    mylabel/.style={text width=7em, text centered} 
}  
\node [mynode](node) {1};\pause
\node [below=of node,mynode](node1){2};
\draw [myarrow] (node.south) -- ++(0,0) -- ++(0,-.2) -|  (node1.north);\pause
\node [left=of node1,mynode](node2){2};
\draw [myarrow] (node.south) -- ++(0,0) -- ++(0,-.2) -|  (node2.north);\pause
\node [left=of node2,mynode](node3){4};
\draw[myarrow] (node.south) -- ++(0,0) -- ++(0,-.2) -|  (node3.north);\pause    
\node [right=of node1,mynode](node4){5};
\draw[myarrow] (node.south) -- ++(0,0) -- ++(0,-.2) -|  (node4.north);\pause
\node [right=of node4,mynode](node5){6};
\draw[myarrow] (node.south) -- ++(0,0) -- ++(0,-.2) -|  (node5.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As a workaround you can use `transparent=0`, which does print the nodes on the slide (they are selectable with the mouse etc.) but they appear the same as when using `invisible`, i.e., you don't see them.

Comment: This works same as transparent, please check the updated MWE

Comment: For me the updated MWE works with a footline on every page with `transparent=0` (and no footlines except for the last page with `invisible`). Maybe you have a different version of `beamer`? In any case it is just a workaround, it does not solve the actual problem but you can use it as a non-perfect solution in case you don't find the 'real' solution.

Comment: My beamer version is v3.55, the problem of transparent or transparent=0 is: when arrows overlapped, the upper line hide the lower line and make it invisible.

Comment: I see what you mean, this is a different problem, another workaround for that can be to avoid drawing the arrows on top of eachother, e.g., instead of drawing from the south of `node`, start drawing halfway down the arrow for the remaining nodes with `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` and `\draw [myarrow] ($(node.south)+(-0.008,-0.2)$) -| (node2.north);\pause`. But it is getting increasingly more desirable to solve the original problem :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21512/pause-in-tikzpicture-breaks-footline

Comment: @Salim Bou yes it is one of workarounds to solve the issue, thanks for mentioning this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dedicated tikzlibrary `overlay-beamer-styles` that makes the tikz commands overlay aware and we can specify on which slides this should be visible by using `\draw<2-5>` and similar

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{warsaw}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\tikzset{
    mynode/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,draw=black, top color=green, bottom color=red!80,very thick, inner sep=1em, minimum size=3em, text centered},
    myarrow/.style={->, >=latex', shorten >=.1pt},%, thick
    mylabel/.style={text width=7em, text centered}
}  

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{content}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.5cm, auto]
\node<1-> [mynode](node) {1};
\node<2-> [below=of node,mynode](node1){2};
\draw<2-> [myarrow] (node.south) -- ++(0,0) -- ++(0,-.2) -|  (node1.north);
\node<3-> [left=of node1,mynode](node2){2};
\draw<3-> [myarrow] (node.south) -- ++(0,0) -- ++(0,-.2) -|  (node2.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```