# Beamer footline dissapears with onslide

Tags: beamer, header-footer, environments

When using `\onslide<n>` with 1<=n<=k the footline will only appear on the slide `\onslide<k>`.

To fix this it was [suggested by Joachim Breitner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70051/125223)  to add a `\onslide<1->` at the end of every environment.

My question is if there is a way to do this automatically with the end of environments, such that all `\end` statements becomes `\onslide<1->\end` statements instead.

And whether this would be smart.

I tried adding a `\onslide<1->` inside the footline definition, but this did not help.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{duckuments}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Singapore}



\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \includegraphics[height = 0.5cm]{example-image-duck}
        \hfill%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
    \insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber\kern1em%
 }


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{The best duck}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \onslide<1> \node at (0,0) {Bob is the best duck, he is in the lower left corner.};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{The day Bob disappeared}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \onslide<1> \node at (0,0) {Ohhh nooo, Bob is gone. };
        \onslide<1> \node at (0,-1) {What frame is this anyways?};
        \onslide<2> \node at (0,0) {Yay Bob is back.};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

Bob was probably just changing clothes in the second slide ;-)