# Keeping the footline when using an animated smart diagram

Tags: beamer, animations, smartdiagram

In my beamer presentation I have a frame where I used an animated smart diagram as follows:

```
\begin{frame}{Title}

\smartdiagramset{description title text width=1.5cm,
description text width=11cm,description width=12cm, descriptive items y sep=55pt}

\smartdiagramanimated[descriptive diagram]{
  {Step 1,{Defining Step 1}},
  {Step 2,{Defining Step 2}},
  {Step 3,{Defining Step 3}},
  {Step 4,{Defining Step 4}}}

\end{frame}
```

The problem is I have a footer that disappears during the animation then after the final step of animation the final slide is repeated with the footer.
My question is how can I make the footer appear during the animation and avoid the duplicated final slide?[image: final step of the animation]

[image: the slide is repeated with the footer]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is basically the same as [\pause in tikzpicture breaks footline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21512/pause-in-tikzpicture-breaks-footline) : on shouldn't use `\pause` within a tikzpicture, otherwise bad things will happen.

The solution is just a bit more complicate as the pause is deeply hidden in the smartdiagram code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\smartdiagramanimated}{r[] m}{%
   \StrCut{#1}{:}\diagramtype\option
   \IfNoValueTF{#1}{% true-no value 1
      \PackageError{smartdiagram}{Type of the diagram not inserted. Please insert it}
      {Example: \protect\smartdiagram[flow diagram]}}
   {%false-no value 1
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{}{%
      \PackageError{smartdiagram}{Type of the diagram not inserted. Please insert it}
      {Example: \protect\smartdiagram[flow diagram]}
   }{}
   \IfStrEq{\diagramtype}{descriptive diagram}{% true-descriptive diagram
   \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={align=center,let hypenation}]
   \foreach \smitem [count=\xi] in {#2}{%
   \edef\col{\@nameuse{color@\xi}}

   \foreach \subitem [count=\xii] in \smitem{%
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro\subitemvisible{\xi}
   \ifnumequal{\xii}{1}{% true
   \visible<+->{\node[description title,drop shadow, smvisible on=<\subitemvisible->]
   (module-title\xi) at (0,0-\xi*\sm@core@descriptiveitemsysep) {\subitem};}
   }{}
   \ifnumequal{\xii}{2}{% true
   \visible<+->{\node[description,drop shadow,smvisible on=<\subitemvisible->]
   (module\xi)at (0,0-\xi*\sm@core@descriptiveitemsysep) {\subitem};}
   }{}
   }%
   }%
   \end{tikzpicture}
   }{}% end-descriptive diagram
   }% end-no value 1
}% end-command

\makeatother



\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}{Title}


\smartdiagramanimated[descriptive diagram]{
  {Step 1,{Defining Step 1}},
  {Step 2,{Defining Step 2}},
  {Step 3,{Defining Step 3}},
  {Step 4,{Defining Step 4}}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Another approach could be to patch `tikzpicture` (use at your own risk, no idea what other problems this might cause):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\AtEndEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\onslide<1->}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}{Title}

\smartdiagramanimated[descriptive diagram]{
  {Step 1,{Defining Step 1}},
  {Step 2,{Defining Step 2}},
  {Step 3,{Defining Step 3}},
  {Step 4,{Defining Step 4}}}

}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```