# No page numbers in Beamer slides with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am making some simple drawings with `TikZ`, and would like to spread the drawings over several slides (ie. on each slide something additional is drawn on the frame). I have succeeded doing it with `\pause` as I would normally do, and, when it doesn't work (when drawing on layers), I use the `visible on=` drawing option which serves the purpose. My only issue is that page numbering is only rendered in the very last page of a given frame, that is, when the drawing is fully complete, just before I pass to the next frame. The paging is actually correct (in the sense that if, the previous frame ended on, say, page 8, and the frame has four steps, then the last slide correctly shows page 12; it's just that, in between, nothing is shown at all).

To do the paging, I have `\setbeamertempate{footline}[page number]` at the top of my latex code.

Besides that, I also have this issue with footnotes, that is, if I have a `\footnotetext{...}` at the end of my frame, it will only show in the very last slide of my frame, no matter what I tried with things like `\pause[...]` or `\onslide<...>{\footnotetext{...}}`.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \pause
    \draw (2,0) rectangle (3,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This will produce a pdf with two pages. The first page will have a single square, without any pagination. The second page will have two squares, with `2/2` written at the bottom right of the page.

Comment: Can you show us an example, when happen your problem? With an MWE, which reproduce your problem?

Comment: @Zarko edited accordingly.

Comment: It seems that the problem is in used `\pause`. For example, `\uncover` doesn't cause such problem: `\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\uncover<2->{
    \draw (2,0) rectangle (3,1);
            }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}` works fine.

Comment: Here is another way to reveal step by step: [(Mindmap) tikzpicture in beamer (reveal step by step)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849/269505)

Comment: In my actual code, I also use `visible on=<...>`, it's just that it was more convoluted than a regular `\pause` so I didn't put it in my MWE.

Comment: There is a very useful hack here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70051/263192. Put `\onslide<1->` last in your `tikzpicture` and it works with `\pause`.

Comment: @user187803 definitively a useful hack, since my drawing code is already hundreds of line long, so it's really a pain to get rid of the `\pause` and convert them to whatever works! I would still be interested in a "real" solution (as opposed to a hack), but this is still very good!